# Member of derived type

Tags: c++, memory, abstract-class, virtual

Consider the following example:

- I have an abstract class `socket`, which defines some virtual interface for a nice object-oriented socket (e.g., `send` and `receive`).
- That class is then specialized in multiple ways, (e.g., in my case, I can have a `TCP` socket or an `UDT` socket, they work in different ways (`UDT` is based on an underlying `UDP` socket, for example) but they have the same interface, i.e., one can e.g. `send` and `receive`.
- I have a `connection` class that should somehow wrap a socket, adding a whole lot of features (e.g. template methods to send and receive objects, it serializes them, everything is beautiful).

Now, the most simple thing I could do in `connection` is to have a `socket *` pointer. The `connection` can then accept in its constructor a pointer and all is nice. However, there is a performance issue there: whenever my `connection` object wants to talk to my `socket` object, there is a dereferencing that requires time.

What I would like to do is to actually have the `socket` as a member of `connection`. Don't take me wrong: I know that, if nothing else, different specializations of `socket` can have different sizes, so I cannot simply do something like: `socket my_pretty_socket;`

### My idea

What I would like to know is if the following idea doesn't make any sense, and why.

I have a finte and limited set of possible specializations of `socket`. What if I built some `template any <typename base, typename... specializations>` that:

- Allocates an array of as many `char`s as the largest of the specializations.
- Offers a template constructor that forwards its parameters to the constructor of the specified specialization, and uses placement `new` on the allocated array to create the object.
- Behaves like a reference to `socket`, e.g. by providing an `operator * ()` or by forwarding each call to the interface of `socket` to the specialization it is storing.

In this way, I would have the object in place as a member of `connection`, and I would preserve all the nice properties of an interface while saving on memory transactions.

1. Is this idea dumb? Why?
2. Are there solutions already in place to do this? I am sure I cannot be the only one to have this kind of problem.

Comment: _"Are there solutions already in place to do this?"_ `boost::asio`

Comment: Uh but in your solution you still have to dereference. You still call through a pointer to socket so you still go through the vtable. The only thing you are changing is where the data is stored. Is that your intent?

Comment: I mean, the actual simplest, and most performant thing to do is simply to get rid of inheritance altogether, and just template the `connection` on the exact type of `socket` it has. Then you pay zero indirection costs whatsoever and it is much simpler than you are trying to do. But `connection` will now have a type dependent on which socket it has active, so you cannot decide at runtime which connection you will use (unless you erase types at a higher level). Is this an issue?

Comment: why dont you show code instead of lengthy descriptions? Actually in that case it would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NirFriedman true, but since the `socket` object is contiguous in memory to the `connection` object, I guess it will have a better chance to avoid cache misses. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NirFriedman yes, that's exactly the issue :) I have no way to know at compile time whether a connection is going to be on top of a `TCP`, `UDT`, etc socket.

Comment: Is `UDT` a typo for `UDP`?

Comment: @Barmar http://udt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The normal way to do this is with a pointer. The derferencing overhead is negligible. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Barmar You are assuming that this is premature. And the cost of a cache miss is quite significant.

Comment: @NirFriedman Compared to the cost of network I/O? I think not.

Comment: I'm with @Barmar here: cache miss, dereferencing, are "slow" compared to what? Here we are talking about network I/O: sending one byte over the wire will require so much more time compared to cache miss or "slow" dereferencing. Go for clean and maintainable code, read about Single Responsability Principle and Separation of Concern. And start worrying about performance only after measuring it. In most (not all) of real word scenarios, your concern about dereferencing performance will be negligible.

Comment: @NirFriedman I've been here long enough to know that 99% of the questions about optimization are premature and/or misguided. I'm willing to pay out on the 1%.

Comment: @Barmar It seems wrong to not give people the benefit of the doubt. For anyone working in HFT, which is a significant chunk of C++ development, this is just a routine optimization.

Comment: @NirFriedman I've been answering programming questions on the Internet for over 30 years. At the risk of bragging, I've got a very good intuition for this kind of thing. 99% of questions about optimization are premature or misguided. I'm willing to pay off on the 1% I'm wrong about. But I'd expect the OP to provide the benchmarking data that supports it.

Comment: @Barmar I have encountered this problem in multiple situations, from networking to high performance simulations. This time I decided to ask if it was possible to do what I had in mind. @NirFriedman answered my question: yes, not only it is possible, but it is actually a recognized issue, and pointed me to `variant`s.

Comment: @Barmar From NirFriedman 's answer I have learned something useful that I will use in the future. A reason I am using SO less and less is that nearly all the answers I get are opinions on why I shouldn't ask the question in the first place, no matter how plain and simple. I shouldn't optimize too early I shouldn't use templates too often I shouldn't work on two-dimensional dynamical systems I shouldn't have written my first programs with my grandpa when I was seven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question + comments, I think your best bet is to simply drop the inheritance and use a `variant`. This solution requires either boost, C++17, or a new-ish compiler/standard library with an implementation of the variant TS, and preferably 14. A variant is a type that stores one of several types. It stores everything on the stack, based on the size of the largest type.

```
struct tcp {
  void do_stuff() const;
};

struct udp {
  void do_stuff() const;
};

using socket_type = std::variant<tcp,udp>;

void do_stuff(const socket_type& s) {
    visit([] (const auto& x) { x.do_stuff(); }, s);
}

enum class SocketKind { TCP, UDP };

template <class ... Args>
socket_type make_socket(SocketKind k, Args && args) {
    if (k == SocketKind::TCP) { return tcp(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    if (k == SocketKind::UDP) { return udp(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }  
}
```

You can create these sockets with a factory like this, and then you can call `do_stuff` generically on a socket object. Everything is stored in-line in memory, and the dispatch will be handled via switch-case which is likely to be faster than vtable if you have a small number of socket types (but that's just a guess).

(Note that I use a variadic lambda to write `do_stuff`, this just simplifies things but isn't really required. You can write out that visitor by hand, so you can still use this solution with even C++03 as long as you can use boost).

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!